# Merge a Facebook login app used for Android with an iOS one, or migrate users to new one

Tags: android, ios, facebook, authentication

A legacy setup we have means that we have the following:

1. Facebook app used for login onto Android devices
2. *Separate* Facebook app used for login on iOS devices

The issue this has caused is that if a user switches between devices they get a 'this email address is already in use' message from our server.

I need to find a way to get any users logging in on the two platforms to just be able to do so, and i assume the best way to do that is to:

- Add Android as a platform on our iOS login
- Change the Android app to use the 'other' login/app id (iOS)
- Log everyone out on next release of our app (on Android)
- Re-authenticate those users on Android as they log in (as we are making them use a new app id)

The key thing is for us however, that

- The Facebook login is associated to their entire account (which is hung off the email address) and they have lots of content in there, so we cannot get those Android users to lose anything
- We need to *let* them do this because we WILL already have used that email address if they are logging back in

Will the above strategy work to do this? Any pointers or recommendations on best strategy for this would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this API to link your users across the two apps:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Just keep the two apps as separate apps and link them under a single business.  Then, when a user logs in you can check if they have already logged in before using the other app.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the direction of this information! I really appreciate it. It looks like the way forward.